# How to disable the default unit of FontSize as "Unit", and force the use of an explicit unit definition?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on XAML files in which FontSize is always to be specified in points.
Example:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="6.5 pt">foobar</TextBlock>
```

Is there a way to make Visual Studio NOT compile in case a suffix is not given?
This is to say, that should the following be written in an XAML file, then Visual Studio should report it as an error.

```
<TextBlock FontSize="6.5">foobar</TextBlock>
```

(For the curious: This is needed on a project in which multiple font sizes are used, and they have to be specified in points. Sometimes developers forget to suffix with 'pt' which messes up the UI)

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do it in that way. The type converter associated with the Text property converts the string "6.5 pt" to a double, and the first you'll be able to see of it is in a value changed handler on the TextProperty dependency property. At that point, all you can get is the double that the converter assigned to FontSize. I would look into adding a rule to your build or source control check-in process (maybe Resharper could do this?) that searches *.xaml for `/FontSize="[0-9\.]+"/` and fails the build or the check-in.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That will do!

Comment: Others, please elaborate on your down-votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make Visual Studio NOT compile in case a suffix is not given?

No, basically. 6.5pt is a valid font size as far as the built-in XAML processor and the built-in `TextBlock` class and `FontSize` property is concerned and there is not much you can do to change this or the way WPF was built by Microsoft.

As @Ed Plunkett suggests you will need enforce some kind of code reviews yourself to prevent such font sizes from getting into your application. But the compiler nor the XAML processor won't be able to help you out.